# Is “would you mind...” a polite form?

Tags: meaning, expressions

A bit of context: I posted an answer on one of the StackExchange websites. A person commented my answer by providing very interesting information. I find that it would be great for this person to write his own answer in order to receive points from the community, so I commented in response:

> Would you mind writing your own answer? [...]

Not being particularly proficient in English, I have a doubt. Is this comment actually polite, or it could be perceived as rude, such as in “mind your own business” or “go make your own answer and stop commenting mine”, which I want to avoid at all costs?

Comment: The [BBC World Service](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv239.shtml) has a good article on polite forms. // It is perhaps more polite to assume that a person answering in a 'comment' is doing so for a valid reason (they may be weighing up borderline questions with a view to close-voting, for instance).

Comment: Don't confuse "would you mind" with "do you mind".  "Do you mind?", when spoken alone, is more likely to be meant as technically polite but really meaning "Hey, you idiot, pay attention/stop doing that/etc."

Comment: What is "acceptable", "polite", etc. is (1) primarily opinion-based and more importantly (2) dependent on the context (as @Tallima rightfully said).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase itself can be used both in a derogatory and favorable way. Context and the reader's voice/mood could make the sentence read either way. Therefore, it may be better to include the full intention of your sentence in plain English:

> Would you mind writing this comment as an answer so that I can mark it
>   as the best answer for others to find and so that you get your
>   well-deserved points?